# How to handle this javascript asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have this function in javascript node

```
exports.getUserEmailByAccess = async (moduleType) => {
  let emailList = []
  const foundUsers = await Access.find({moduleType:moduleType})
  console.log(foundUsers);

  await foundUsers.forEach(access => {
      User.findById(access.userId)
      .then(foundUser => {
          console.log(foundUser.workerEmail);
          emailList.push(foundUser.workerEmail)
      })
      
  });

   console.log(emailList);
   return emailList

}
```

What I want is to push into **emailList** array by looping object array, the above approach results in an empty array,so I tried a different following way

```
exports.getUserEmailByAccess = async (moduleType) => {
  let emailList = []
  const foundUsers = await Access.find({moduleType:moduleType})
  console.log(foundUsers);

  await foundUsers.forEach(access => {
      const foundUser = User.findById(access.userId)
      console.log(foundUser.workerEmail);
      emailList.push(foundUser.workerEmail)
      
  });
  console.log(emailList);

  return emailList

 
}
```

By doing this , the array list is getting filled but with an [undefined]**strong text** value, I come from a humble python control structure background, Please can I know why I am not able to push data into array even after using async/await

Comment: does `foundUsers.forEach` return a ***Promise*** - if not, you can't await it ... I'm assuming that is NOT Array forEach, in which case, never use Array forEach with async/await, unless you REALLY know what you're doing - and even then, there's always better ways to do it

Comment: @Bravo is right, `forEach` doesn't wait for the promise to be resolved, instead you should use a `for` loop.

Comment: the answer depends if you can `User.findById` in parallel or in series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `User.findById()` returns a promise, I'd recommend using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead of individually running all promises using `forEach` to fetch documents of all `foundUsers`:

```js
exports.getUserEmailByAccess = async (moduleType) => {
  const foundUsers = await Access.find({ moduleType: moduleType });
  console.log(foundUsers);

  const userDocs = await Promise.all(
    foundUsers.map((user) => User.findById(user.userId))
  );
  const emailList = userDocs.map((user) => user.workerEmail);
  // or alternatively
  // const emailList = userDocs.map(({workerEmail}) => workerEmail);

  console.log(emailList);
  return emailList;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give try this

```
exports.getUserEmailByAccess = async (moduleType) => {
    let emailList = []
    const foundUsers = await Access.find({ moduleType: moduleType })
    console.log(foundUsers);

    await foundUsers.map(async access => {
        let result = await User.findById(access.userId);
        if (result) {
            emailList.push(foundUser.workerEmail)
        }

    });

    console.log(emailList);
    return emailList
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
await Promise.all(
     foundUsers.map(async access => {
        let result = await User.findById(access.userId);
        if (result) {
            emailList.push(foundUser.workerEmail)
        }

    })
])

console.log(emailList);
return emailList
```

Comment: `map` won't wait for the async function to be resolved, the `emailList` will remain empty.

Comment: Array map also doesn't return a Promise - so this is just as bad ... usually it's something like `await Promise.all(array.map .....` if you want to do things parallel

Comment: Yes ,it still returns empty array

Answer (score 1):

How are your Models related? I think you might do a populate here if the Access Model has the ObjectId of the User Model. Something like this:

```
const foundUsers = await Access.find({ moduleType: moduleType }).populate({
  path: 'users', // the name of the field which contains the userId
  select: '-__v' // fields to bring from database. Can add a (-) to NOT bring that field
})
```

The idea is that you specify all the fields that you need. Then when you receive the data, you can do something like:

```
foundUsers.users.email
```

Comment: "Can add a (-) to NOT bring that field", you can also specify that in your query using [projections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)